# How do I switch back to LightDM from GDM3 in Ubuntu Mate 18.10

Tags: lightdm, 18.10, gdm, ubuntu-mate, display-manager

So while trying to solve Logitech TouchPad T650 intermittent freezing issue, I installed Solaar ( https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/ ) via Synaptic. During the installation, it asked me to select between GDM3 and LightDM and I accidentally selected GDM3.

So now I'm stuck with GDM3 (to me it feels like being blinded). So far I've tried the following few times and rebooted few times but to no avail. The command runs just find but after reboot, it just goes back to GDM3.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

And on top of this TouchPad has kinda stopped working... while cursor moves, left/right click is not working. It's a desktop PC running Ubuntu Mate 18.10 64bit.

I like to get back to LightDM and remove Solaar, GDM3, etc.. completely. Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest solution would be to remove GDM3 completely with

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm3
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then reboot.

To remove Solaar you can use

```
sudo apt-get purge solaar solaar-gnome3
```

To remove *Ubuntu on Wayland* from LightDM use the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-session xwayland
```

also you can remove other GNOME parts with

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and reboot.

Comment: Right before your answer, I figured out that reconfigure lightdm was working but the system was booting in to Wayland or default Ubuntu desktop environment. So I logged out and logged in to Mate. Now is safe to remove Wayland DE? How could I do that please.

Comment: Great that it helped. So we can remove comments below the answer. I have removed my.